# iOS 10 device , not receiving notification in production mode, but development is working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

My app is live in iTunes Connect. To give support of `iOS 10` I am using same `certificate` and `provisioning` that I was using in the last version. Currently, my `XCode` version is **`8.1 (8B62)`**. I am receiving remote notifications in development. But when I am testing the app in `TestFlight`, I am not receiving any remote notification. But It was working fine up to `iOS 9` with `XCode 7`.

Here is my `AppDelegate.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
@import UserNotifications;
#endif

#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>
#else
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
#endif

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (copy ,nonatomic) void(^backgroundSessionCompletionHandler)();


@end

// Copied from Apple's header in case it is missing in some cases (e.g. pre-Xcode 8 builds).
#ifndef NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max
#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max 1299
#endif
```

Here is my `AppDelegate.m`

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

#pragma mark - Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    [self initPushnotificationService];

    [self decideViewController]; 

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // SOME CODE
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // SOME CODE
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{    
    // SOME CODE
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // SOME CODE
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
        // SOME CODE
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken
{
        // SOME CODE
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app
didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {

        // SOME CODE
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
   withResponseInfo:(NSDictionary *)responseInfo
  completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler{

        // SOME CODE
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
forRemoteNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
   withResponseInfo:(NSDictionary *)responseInfo
  completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler{

        // SOME CODE
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    // SOME CODE
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{

    // SOME CODE

}

#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
#pragma mark  FOREGROUND Delegate
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {

    // SOME CODE
}
#pragma mark  BACKGROUND Delegate
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler {

        // SOME CODE
}
#endif


#pragma mark - push notification setup
-(void)initPushnotificationService{

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *viewMessageAction;
    viewMessageAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [viewMessageAction setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
    [viewMessageAction setTitle:@"Say OK"];
    [viewMessageAction setIdentifier:NotificationActionSayOkMessage];
    [viewMessageAction setDestructive:NO];
    [viewMessageAction setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *replyMessageAction;
    if( __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_9_0){
        replyMessageAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
        [replyMessageAction setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
        [replyMessageAction setTitle:@"Reply"];
        [replyMessageAction setBehavior:UIUserNotificationActionBehaviorTextInput];
        [replyMessageAction setIdentifier:NotificationActionReplyMessage];
        [replyMessageAction setDestructive:NO];
        [replyMessageAction setAuthenticationRequired:NO];
    }
    else{
        replyMessageAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
        [replyMessageAction setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground];
        [replyMessageAction setTitle:@"Reply"];
        [replyMessageAction setIdentifier:NotificationActionReplyMessage];
        [replyMessageAction setDestructive:NO];
        [replyMessageAction setAuthenticationRequired:NO];
    }

    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *viewMessageActionactionCategory;
    viewMessageActionactionCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
    [viewMessageActionactionCategory setIdentifier:NotificationCategoryViewMessage];
    [viewMessageActionactionCategory setActions:@[viewMessageAction, replyMessageAction]
                                     forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

    NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:viewMessageActionactionCategory];

    // Register for remote notifications
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
        /// iOS 7.1 or earlier. Disable the deprecation warnings.
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:categories];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
    }
    else
    {        /// iOS 8 or later
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
            UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
            (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:categories];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        }
        else{
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0


            UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;

            [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
             requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
             completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                 if( !error ){
                     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
                 }

                 @try {
                     UNNotificationAction *sayOkMessageAction = [UNNotificationAction actionWithIdentifier:NotificationActionSayOkMessage title:@"Say OK" options:UNNotificationActionOptionAuthenticationRequired];


                     UNTextInputNotificationAction *replyMessageAction = [UNTextInputNotificationAction actionWithIdentifier:NotificationActionReplyMessage title:@"Reply" options:UNNotificationActionOptionAuthenticationRequired textInputButtonTitle:@"Reply" textInputPlaceholder:@"Message"];


                     UNNotificationCategory *messageCategory = [UNNotificationCategory categoryWithIdentifier:NotificationCategoryViewMessage actions:@[sayOkMessageAction,replyMessageAction] intentIdentifiers:@[NotificationActionSayOkMessage,NotificationActionReplyMessage] options:UNNotificationCategoryOptionCustomDismissAction];

                     NSSet *categories_set = [NSSet setWithObject:messageCategory];

                     [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setNotificationCategories:categories_set];

                     /// For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                     [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];


                 }
                 @catch (NSException *exception) {
                     NSLog(@"%@",exception);
                 }
             }
             ];

#endif
        }
    }

}


@end
```

Comment: For didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken call in xcode 8.1 have to check : Target >> capabilities >> Push Notificationa (2 option) have to ON ...then check ..may it's help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]@soumenSardar - 
For new xode 8.1, you have to add a entitlement file

Targets ---> Capabilities and verify Push Notifications is all correct on that view --> Fix it.

It should works

Be careful push notifications are off by default in xcode 8.1

Comment: please check entitlement file.
And set APN Environment as production

Comment: I changed `APS Environment` value to `production` from `development` in `.entitlement` file. After that I noticed `Target > capabilities > Push Notification(Option 2)` went `red`. I clicked **Fix Issue** button. Go back to check `. entitlement` , noticed `APS Environment` value become `development`. Then I did all of the states many times. But resulting nothing.  `Target > capabilities > Push Notification` making the `APS Environment` value to `development` and manual `APS Environment` value `production` changing  `Target > capabilities > Push Notification`  to `red` and asking for fix issue.

Comment: Please set manual APS Environment value  as production and leave the error warning as it is. And prepare a build for production. You should get push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Check you PushNotification Certificates. Either they are revoked or may be not created correctly or may be you are using wrong certificates for distribution.

Comment: Sure!. I will check and let you know. But what I did , I just updated the XCode version.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps I follow if push is not working in production mode

1. Make sure your SANDBOX is OFF
2. Ask developer & make sure they are using production aps file
3. Make sure your provision profile is created after you add push notification setting.

Usually I found `Option 1` is what they didn't make.

If Option 1, 2, 3 are fine, check from your end for coding.

Comment: Can you please explain `Option 1`? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @SoumenSardar : That option is available with web developer... who is sending push? web developer... right?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar problem when switched fron XCode 7.x to XCode 8.x. Try check in `Capabilities` the `Push Notifications` switch setting is ON:

[image]

The rilevant part is the second check, previosly it was handled by XCode under your radar, now it's a setting you must enable.